Errors when enabling authentication for an Angular application in Azure Static Web App
I'm hosting an Angular application in Azure Static Web App and having some problem with implementing autentication. My goal is to have the entire web app behind Entra ID authentication. My staticwebapp.config.json looks like this:
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html"
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"],
      "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": "no-store"
      }
    }
  ],
  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "statusCode": 302,
      "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad"
    }
  },
  "auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "ISSUER",
          "clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And the issue I'm having is that sometimes the page fails to load and I get the following errors in the console
Refused to apply style from 'https://<url>/.auth/login/aad' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. on the root-url
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. on /.auth/complete
When I tried to remove the responseOverrides I could see that some of the requests for fetching js-files failed with 401. This was a bit strange because it would fail on different files every time I reloaded the page. The cookie-values were the same for requests that failed and succeeded.
Am I doing something wrong in my configuration file?

Refer the steps below in order to successfully add authentication in Javascript Azure static web app:-
My Azure static web authentication app sample repository.
Create a new Azure AD app registration and add
the settings below:-

Copy Application (client) ID and Directory (Tenant) ID.
In the Authentication tab of Azure AD app> Add a platform > Web and Add the Redirect URI> yourstaticwebappurl/.auth/login/aad/callback > ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)

Create one client secret and copy it somewhere:-

In API permissions check if the User.Read permission is present:-

Create a new file in your repository:-
Add the Directory (Tenant) ID copied above from Azure AD app Overview tab:-
staticwebapp.config.json
{
     “routes”: [
          {
         “route”: “/”,
                “allowedRoles”: [ “authenticated” ]
       }
     ],
     “responseOverrides”: {
             “401”: {
               “redirect”: “/.auth/login/aad”,
               “statusCode”: 302
             }
           },
     “auth”: {
       “identityProviders”: {
         “azureActiveDirectory”: {
           “registration”: {
             “openIdIssuer”: “https://login.microsoftonline.com/DirectoryTenantId“</font>,
             “clientIdSettingName”: “AADClientID”,
             “clientSecretSettingName”: “AADSecret”
           },”userDetailsClaim”: “http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name”
                 }
       }
     }
   }
</font></p>

In Azure Static Web app Configuration or Environment variables add copied Application (client) ID and Client Secret:-
AADClientID:xxxxxxxx7ff6b5
AADSecret:XxxxxxxxxNaRW


Make sure your create your Azure static web app with Standard hosting plan:-
Output:-



Reference:-
Walkthrough Static Web Apps And Aad Authentication | Jeff Sanders Technical Blog (jsandersrocksblog.github.io)

try making your authentication routes anonymous
  "route": "/login",
  "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad",
  "allowedRoles": [ "anonymous" ]
},
{
  "route": "/.auth/login/aad",
  "allowedRoles": [ "anonymous" ]
},

and add exceptions to your navigationFallback for your external resources
"navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "/index.html",
      "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
  }

